# Firefox SVG filter on a different domain

Tags: firefox, dns, svg, svg-filters

For example, my HTML file with CSS declaration 'filter:url(http://example2.com/svgfile.svg#myfilter);' in it is located on the domain 'example1.com'. Does it work in Firefox? It works when the HTML file and the SVG file are on the same domain.

Answer (score 4):

SVG resource documents have to be same-origin with the loading page in Gecko.  Otherwise you could examine the resulting rendering and read cross-domain information about the resource document...

At some point, this codepath will likely grow a CORS check.